# Prevent iOS app to fade in/out audio volume when playing on Bluetooth speakers

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, avspeechsynthesizer

I'm using `AVSpeechSynthesizer` to let my iOS app talk. It works well when the iPad has no Bluetooth speaker connected. It always talk and the volume doesn't fade in when the speech starts.

However, as soon as Bluetooth speakers are connected to the iOS device, the volume fades when `AVSpeechSynthesizer` starts talking, leading to an effect where you can't properly here the first few words.

How can I disable this behavior?

Comment: Trying changing around the volume setting in AVSpeechUtterance. I believe if you set the volume constant to maximum volume then this behavior will not occur. I personally have not tested this recently with Bluetooth.

Comment: Thanks – tried it and it still fades in when the speech starts

Comment: 9 year bump :) ever found a solution?

Comment: I jumped the Apple ship a while ago :-)